# anime.js querySelectorAll() in external SVG breaks [NodeList] for attribute 'targets:'

Tags: svg, external, nodelist, anime.js

I'm trying to animate all `<rect>` within an SVG with anime.js.

As long as the SVG is inline, I can call a `querySelectorAll()` or `getElementsByTagName()` and take this nodelist as the attribute for `targets:` and all selected elements will be animated.

```
elements = document.querySelectorAll("rect");
```

inside anime code

```
targets: elements,
```

**BUT**: When I link the same **SVG code to an external SVG** (embeded with an `<object>` element), anime.js stopps working (only FireFox will work,still) when I set

```
elements2 = document.getElementById("SVG").contentDocument.querySelectorAll("rect");

targets: elements2,
```

When I get single elements for the `targets:` attribute like

```
targets: elements2[0|,
```

anime.js will animate the single element.

A function will not work, too.

```
targets: function(i){return elements2[i];},
```

How can I get the elements as targets in an external SVG in Edge/IE/Safari/Chrome to be animated with anime.js?

Comment: Please also include the code that shows this behavior and all the necessary info to reproduce it, ideally a minimal, working test case (for example against some Wikipedia SVG as "external"). You can use the code snippet feature in the question editor (works like jsfiddle) to make runnable code sample, too.

Comment: Only IE/Edge? Have you tried any other browser?

Comment: @RobertLongson ...oh as I see it only works in Firefox. Does not work in Chrome and Safari, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only workaround for anime.js and an external SVG seems to be, to collect all elements in a new array and use this as `targets:` attribute.

```
var elements3 = new Array();

elements2 = document.getElementById("SVG").contentDocument.querySelectorAll("rect");

for (i = 0; i<elements2.length; i++) {
    elements3.push(elements2[i]);
}

targets: elements3,
```

But I do not understand why this is necessary...

Comment: Could you please also share your html code so that I could reprodcue your issue and find the reason?

Comment: @JeniferJiang working example with svg inline: https://jsfiddle.net/hirschferkel/xy5mb3kp/3/

Comment: @JeniferJiang store svg code as it is in an external file and use this not working example code: https://jsfiddle.net/hirschferkel/xy5mb3kp/12/

Comment: @JeniferJiang anyway it's abug in anime.js as there are some more related to external svg.